# How to fix Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException?

Tags: java, selenium

I have used java8 version and i have tested first selenium script with Firefox, but I get the following exception.

> `Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: java.net.ConnectException: Failed to connect to localhost/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:20099
>   Build info: version: '3.141.0', revision: '2ecb7d9a', time: '2018-10-31T20:22:52'
>   System info: host: 'TEST', ip: '', os.name: 'Windows 8.1', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.3', java.version: '1.8.0_211'
>   Driver info: driver.version: FirefoxDriver
>       at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:92)
>       at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:552)
>       at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:213)
>       at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:131)
>       at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:147)
>       at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:125)
>       at test.FistSeleniumTest.main(FistSeleniumTest.java:17)
>   Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Failed to connect to localhost/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:20099
>       at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection.connectSocket(RealConnection.java:247)
>       at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection.connect(RealConnection.java:165)
>       at okhttp3.internal.connection.StreamAllocation.findConnection(StreamAllocation.java:257)
>       at okhttp3.internal.connection.StreamAllocation.findHealthyConnection(StreamAllocation.java:135)
>       at okhttp3.internal.connection.StreamAllocation.newStream(StreamAllocation.java:114)
>       at okhttp3.internal.connection.ConnectInterceptor.intercept(ConnectInterceptor.java:42)
>       at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
>       at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121)
>       at okhttp3.internal.cache.CacheInterceptor.intercept(CacheInterceptor.java:93)
>       at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
>       at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121)
>       at okhttp3.internal.http.BridgeInterceptor.intercept(BridgeInterceptor.java:93)
>       at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
>       at okhttp3.internal.http.RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.intercept(RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.java:126)
>       at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
>       at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121)
>       at okhttp3.RealCall.getResponseWithInterceptorChain(RealCall.java:200)
>       at okhttp3.RealCall.execute(RealCall.java:77)
>       at org.openqa.selenium.remote.internal.OkHttpClient.execute(OkHttpClient.java:103)
>       at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:102)
>       at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:74)
>       at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:136)
>       at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:83)
>       ... 6 more
>   Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
>       at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.waitForConnect(Native Method)
>       at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(DualStackPlainSocketImpl.java:85)
>       at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
>       at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
>       at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
>       at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:172)
>       at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
>       at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
>       at okhttp3.internal.platform.Platform.connectSocket(Platform.java:129)
>       at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection.connectSocket(RealConnection.java:245)`

Comment: Please read: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question). Also, dumping your stack trace is not really helpful. Please take the [tour] and read [How do i ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: "Failed to connect to localhost/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:20099" is quite clear to me. Are you able to connect this URL manualy?

Answer (score 0):

Can you check the gecko driver.exe is placed in your machine and the path is given before the driver object is created.

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "path of the gecko driver exe");
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
```

If this is working fine, can you show me the code for the above.